# Javascript Calculate Time including over night

Tags: javascript, html

I have create code for calculating between 2 time which result in minutes. 
It works fine if no overnight hour (example: `10:00` - `12:00`, `14:00` - `16:00`) the problem comes when I fill it with `23:00` and `01:00` (11 pm to 1 am), it return minus and count backward. You can see my code at snippet below.

Anyone know how to count it normally if there's an overnight? Or it's not possible if there's no date?

```js
function parseTime(s) {
    var c = s.split(':');
    return (parseInt(c[0]) * 60) + parseInt(c[1]);
}
function getTotalMin(x)
{
    var awal = document.getElementById("awaljkab").value;
    var akhir = document.getElementById("akhirjkab").value;
    var selisih = parseTime(akhir) - parseTime(awal);
    x.value = String(selisih);
}
```

```html
<!-- input clock as HH:mm ; example: 10:00 -->
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="startjkab" id="awaljkab" />
<input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" name="finishjkab" id="akhirjkab" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lamajkab" onfocus="getTotalMin(this);" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Fiddle which you had earlier was better idea than snippet in your post.

Comment: Sometimes I confused when asking in here, people try to edit my question to snippet...

Comment: Because the best way is to show your problem code in post but also prepare environment to faster help you by other people

Comment: @suvroc Actually I believe snippets are more recommend, as it does not rely on an outside source. In fact the point of them is to replace fiddles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add 24 hours to second value if it is less than first one

```
var to = parseTime(akhir);
var from = parseTime(awal);
var selisih;
if (to < from)
{
    selisih = 24*60 + to - from;
} else {
    selisih = to - from;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lse3sk44/1/

Comment: after trial and error, I use Your code and works more relevant. Because it count until it minutes. Thanks suvroc

Answer (score 2):

Before calculating `selisih` you should check if the second hour is smaller than the first one:

```
if (akhir < awal) akhir += 24 * 60;
```

That way you ensure that `akhir` represents the following day. After that, you can calculate `selih` the way you did.

Comment: Okay.. still need to wait 3 minutes

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry for the hurries

Comment: after trial and error, I use suvroc code and works more relevant. Because it count until it minutes. I try to fill 23:30 as start and 01:30 as end, it result 300090